# NoUiSlider does not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, nouislider

I'm trying to set up noUiSlider.

My html is

```
<div id="slider" class"noUiSlider"></div>
```

My javascript

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        start: 10,
        range: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        },
        pips: {
            mode: 'values',
            values: [20, 80],
            density: 4
        }
    });
```

The javascript is exactly the code from the website (examples page, last example).

That's how my slider looks like:
[image]
Both javascript and css files are correctly implemented.

Any ideas why it's not working?

**UPDATE**: As jsfiddle didn't work, here is a CodePen example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXVoyO

Comment: Attach a jsfiddle. If the code is exactly the same of the examples, you have anything that is overriding styles. Please, make a jsfiddle.net and share us

Comment: jsfiddle didn't work, I put it in CodePen. I updated the question

Comment: What is the problem? The visualization of the values or you try to update values when slide?

Comment: It's the visualization. It should look like on this page: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/ (last example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin doesn't styling these values. You need to apply custom CSS to the elements:

```
.noUi-value.noUi-value-horizontal.noUi-value-large {
     position: absolute;
 }
```

With this rule, you have the 20% and 80% values in bottom of their position in slider. If you want to stylize much more, you need to apply custom CSS to this elements, or attach elements to `update()` function of the plugin:

```
slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
   //on slide you can update values and items.
});
```

See it working:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpEXQP

Comment: Thank you. But that's strange. I thought it would style it automatically. But I noticed another problem: 20% and 80% should be borders. You should not be able to get to e.g. 10%. That means, the script isn't working as well

Comment: The values that you see now are to view where are this values in the slider. The plugin works perfectly. If you need to update the values you need to use the second block of code. When user slide the slider, you must to update the value.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Thought this was optional

Comment: In the examples that you tell me, if you see "Non linear slider" example you can view this code: `nonLinearSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function ( values, handle ) {
 if ( !handle ) {
  lowerValue.innerHTML = values[handle] + ', ' + leftValue(handles[handle]);
 } else {
  upperValue.innerHTML = values[handle] + ', ' + leftValue(handles[handle]);
 }
});` It was to update the values. (here: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-non-linear )